# add text before block is being displayed in region content

Tags: blocks, theming

I have a block that I want to display in my *Content* region which works fine but the block is always fix aligned in the top left corner (`float: left` property). How can I set it so, that my content displays above the block in my region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign this css code to one class of your block ( or the #id )

```
.your-block-class-name:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
```

Comment: I tried this like: `div#block-simplenews-0:before {
￼  content: "";
￼  display: table;
}` but nothing happened, maybe you could have a look at the page yourself: http://spabc.com/content/hills-restoration-process - I'd like to have the block `id="block-simplenews-0"` displayed below `id="block-system-main"`

Comment: switch the order in admin/structure/block and set the Main page content block before the block-simplenews